# xDB index rebuild gets stuck and get Request Entity Too Large exceptions

Tags: solr, xdb, index

I encountered an issue during a manual trigger of an xDB index rebuild. The process appears to get stuck at approximately 7%, and despite waiting for hours, there's no further progress.

[image]

Upon inspecting the logs, we identified an exception related to the problem:

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 413 (Request Entity Too Large).
```

We are using Sitecore 10.3 into an Azure PAAS infrastructure with Solr 8.11.2 installed into an Azure web app.

Any insights or suggestions on how to address this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

After investigating various configurations on both Solr and xc-search roles, we identified that the problem stems from the Solr web app's IIS restriction on requests size.

To address this, we added the following lines of code to the web.config file of the Solr web app:

```
 <system.webServer>   
     <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" maxUrl="32768" maxQueryString="32768" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

This adjustment resolved our issue.